# Bash. Сравнение и отличия 2>&1 и &>

Tags: bash

Штудирую и проверяю свои "знания" в bash.
Столкнулся с непониманием  `2>&1` и `&>`

1. `2>&1` перенаправление стандартного вывода ошибок (stderr) в тот же устройство вывода, что и стандартный вывод (stdout).

```bash
ls -al /etc/passwd /fake_file>output.txt 2>&1
cat output.txt
```

Результат

```
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/fake_file': Нет такого файла или каталога
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2310 мар 14 22:49 /etc/passwd
```

2. `&>` перенаправление стандартного вывода ошибок (`stderr`), так стандартного вывода (`stdout`) в файл или устройство вывода

```
ls -al /etc/passwd /fake_file &> output.txt
cat output.txt
```

```
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/fake_file': Нет такого файла 
или каталога
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2310 мар 14 22:49 /etc/passwd
```

Объясните пожалуйста разницу  `2>&1` и `&>`

Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)

ls -al /etc/passwd /fake_file> output.txt 2>&1 и 
ls -al /etc/passwd /fake_file &> output.txt Форма записи разная, результат один и тот же. 
Перенаправление понятно. 
Как на это посмотреть со стороны "чистоты кода"?

P.S. С точки зрения логики, в конкретном случае запись ls -al /etc/passwd /fake_file &> output.txt является более "эстетичной".
Но есть одно но.
Все зависит от того, для каких оболочек, например, пишется скрипт.
Разные оболочки могут не поддерживать используемые записи:
zsh - поддерживает &>
dash - >file 2>&1

Answer (score 2):

`2>&1` перенаправляет `stderr` в `stdout`, при этом `stdout` не меняется. `&>/some/file` пренаправляет оба потока, и `stderr` и `stdout`, в `/some/file`

В обоих примерах вы перенаправили оба потока в `output.txt`

В первом примере вы сначала перенаправили в этот файл `stdout` инструкцией `>output.txt`, затем перенаправили `stderr` в `stdout`.

Во втором примере вы сразу перенаправили оба потока в `output.txt` инструкцией `&>output.txt`.

Обратите внимание, что в первом примере важен порядок перенаправлений

```
$ ls -al /etc/passwd /fake_file 2>&1 >output.txt
ls: cannot access '/fake_file': No such file or directory
$ cat output.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1987 Jun  8  2020 /etc/passwd
```

В этом примере СНАЧАЛА перенаправляется `stderr` в `stdout` - на тот момент `stdout` был связан с консолью, поэтому сообщение об ошибке `ls: cannot access '/fake_file': No such file or directory` было напечатано в консоли.
`stdout` был перенаправлен в `output.txt`, поэтому вывод `ls` оказался в этом файле.